# Collection и ArrayList в Java

Tags: java, полиморфизм

В чём преимущество такой записи:

```
Collection collection = new ArrayList();
```

перед такой:

```
ArrayList collection = new ArrayList();
```

Ведь мы теряем уникальные методы ArrayList в 1-ом варианте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ведь мы теряем уникальные методы ArrayList в 1-ом варианте?

Нет не теряете. В обоих вариантах вы создаете обьект `ArrayList`. Разница заключается в том, что используя 1-ый вариант вы можете делать так:

```
collection = new LinkedList();
collection = new HashSet();
```

и т.д (то есть, если в будущем Вы поймете что порядок элементов для Вас не важен и, следовательно, захотите использовать `HashSet` вместо `ArrayList` Вам нужно будет изменить меньше кода). Если говорить конкретнее, то в 1-ом варианте Вы указываете, что переменная с именем `collection` имеет тип `Collection`. Так как `Collection` это интерфейс, который реализовуют все коллекции, то Вы можете сослаться на любую коллекцию.

Comment: Понял, мы можем сменить тип коллекции в случае необходимости, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @АндрейКозицкий если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).